# zparseopt : mandatory argument not removed from the options

Tags: zsh

I reduced my problem to this minimal example:

```
# This is script myscript
echo $ZSH_VERSION
zparseopts -D vxa:=opt_a  vx:=opt_b
echo $1
```

I'm calling the script with

```
zsh myscript -vxa xx -vx zz a
```

I would expect that after processing the options, `$1` would output `a`, but I get

```
5.8
xx
```

being printed. Why is this the case?

I am aware about a problem with my script, which is that the option `vx` is a prefix of `vxa`, and when I modify the script to

```
zparseopts -D vxa:=opt_a  vxb:=opt_b
```

and call it accordingly, I indeed get the expected result (`a`) in the output. So, I can fix my script by just renaming the options so that neither one is a prefix of a different option.

However, I also would like to understand, why I see the `xx` with my original code. There is no error in the invocation (if I replace the `-D` by `-F`, I don't get an error message). I could understand it, if my original script would simply fill the wrong variable (taking *vx* as an abbreviation for *vxa*), but I don't understand, why the script silently stops parsing after consuming the `-vxa` option, but not even picking up the mandatory argument *xx*. What is going on here, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's due to the overlapping names + ambiguity regarding how `-vxa` should be parsed vs `-vx a` (the issue being that both are being taken as a `-vx` option with option-arg `a` - its mandatory arg has been consumed, and the unhyphenated `xx` looks like a non-option so parsing stops without any error).

`man zshmodules` has some useful info (bold emphasis added):

> In all cases, option-arguments must appear either immediately following the option in the same positional parameter or in the next one. ...
>
> When the names of two options that take no arguments overlap, the longest one wins, so that parsing for the specs `-foo -foobar` (for example) is unambiguous. However, due to the aforementioned handling of option-arguments, ambiguities may arise **when at least one overlapping spec takes an argument,** as in `-foo: -foobar`. In that case, **the last matching spec wins.**

If the specs are swapped around so that the shorter of the overlapping names are placed before longer ones (i.e. `zparseopts -D vx:=opt_b  vxa:=opt_a`) it should work as you expect. For example:

```
#!/bin/zsh -
echo $ZSH_VERSION
zparseopts -D vx:=opt_b  vxa:=opt_a
print -r -- arg:$^@ opt_a:$^opt_a opt_b:$^opt_b
```

```
$ zsh thatScript -vxa xx -vx zz a
5.9
arg:a opt_a:-vxa opt_a:xx opt_b:-vx opt_b:zz
```